# How can i get latitude and longitude for landmark in meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have city, state and country values in a collection. Now my question is: how do i get latitude and longitude in meteor for a specified city in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for `Geocoding`. There are several Meteor packages that are available to achieve this. You can look for Meteor packages on https://atmospherejs.com/

Here's one of the many packages that solves your problem: https://atmospherejs.com/aldeed/geocoder